# Jquery - Displaying a Div by concatenating variable with string

Tags: jquery, html

I couldn't really explain myself in the title

So I have a lot of divs with the `id`'s `n1_pop, n2_pop` etc

I want to make a dynamic script that once the `n1` is clicked, the div `n1_pop` is displayed.

```
    // POP UP
    $('.completo').click(function(){
        var divid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        $(divid + '_pop').slideDown();
    });
```

I'm here testing and testing but I can't seem to make this work. What I am doing wrong? How can I fix my script?

Some help would be appreaciated.

Comment: Aren't you missing the '#' in your selector?  $('#' + divid + '_pop').slideDown();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing id selector while targeting `n1_pop`:

```
$('#'+divid + '_pop')
```

**Full Snippet:**

```
 $('.completo').click(function(){
    var divid = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    $('#'+divid + '_pop').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're trying to do the equivalent of $(n1_pop'). but you should be doing $('#n1_pop'):

```
// POP UP
    $('.completo').click(function(){
        var divid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        $('"#' + divid + '_pop').slideDown(); /*change this line */
    });
```